# How can I set SSH firewall rule on Google VM so that only my office computers can access the VM over SSH?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, vpc

In last few days my Google VM is continuously being compromised, I have received warning and faced suspension of VM by Google saying "cryptocurrency mining activities was found on VM". I suspect someone has hacked my VM and doing this activity. So, now I want to create a new VM with secure SSH firewall such that only limited computers can access the VM.

I have tried setting the IP of my office routers on firewall ssh allow rule, but after setting this rule also SSH connection to VM do get established from other IP addresses. I just want to specify two IPs in firewall rule but it expects IP ranges in CIDR format (with which I am not clear).

I have also found some suggestions that I should change the ssh port of the VM.

Can anybody please explain how can I restrict the access to my Google VM to only a specific set of computers when this computers are connected to a router and external IP is same for all i.e. of router?

Thanks

Comment: I have voted to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the help center. You should post questions about professional server administration to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to create a new VM  with secure firewall SSH and want to restrict and allow access from particular IP addresses of your office router.

To do that you can create firewall rules as explained here [1](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). To manage the access for a specific instance, I recommend you to use Network Tags for firewall rules [2](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags#targets_for_firewall_rules).

Going back to your concern, that SSH connection to VM do get established from other IP addresses even when you create the firewall rule for the specific IP address. The reason for that might be due to this:

Every project you create in GCP comes with the default firewall rules.
So there might be one default-allow-ssh rule which you need to block, I guess that might be causing the issue. Note that the default network includes some additional rules that override this one, allowing certain types of incoming traffic. See the attached link[3][4] for more details.

[3]https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules 
[4]https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc

You can also add guest-level firewall rule using for example "iptables" to add another security level to your VM instance. However, GCP project-level firewall rule takes care of inspecting network traffic before it goes to your VM instances. Operating system Firewall blocks all internet traffic to any port 22.

In order to allow a specific address to be able to connect on your VM instance, you may add a CIDR of /32 on the "IP ranges" value of your "default-allow-ssh" GCP firewall rule. For example, 45.56.122.7/32 and 208.43.25.31/32.

Comment: Thanks, Firewall settings with network tags and CIDR of /32 solved the problem.